# Property 'Template.TemplateId' of type 'object' has unknown object type 'Decimal128'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am trying to use Realm React Native SDK where I am trying to create a dataset which has some id with `long int` type. I'm using `Decimal128` type in my schema, as mentioned in the realm documentation, but it throws the following error,

> Property 'Template.TemplateId' of type 'object' has unknown object type
> 'Decimal128'

Here's the code:

```
const TemplateSchema = {
  name: "Template",
  properties: {
    Description: "string",
    Status: "int",
    TemplateCode: "string",
    TemplateId: "Decimal128",
    TemplateName: "string",
  },
};

let newTemplates;
realm.write(() => {
  newTemplate = realm.create("STGTemplate", {
    Description: "TEST Desc",
    Status: 0,
    TemplateCode: "TEST 01",
    TemplateId: 1486202620914,
    TemplateName: "Test Template",
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you try "decimal128" instead of "Decimal128"? See the [Field Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/data-types/field-types/) reference.

Comment: No I didn't. I'll try and let you know

Comment: Hi @Jay `decimal128` doesn't work either

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? Is it showing the same error? What version of the SDK are you using? Can you try just using `decimal` instead of `decimal128` and then last thing, when assigning a number to TemplateId, try using a decimal number `3.14` for example. Also, best practice in coding is that properties should be lower-cased; upper case is reserved for Classes, Structures and Enums.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, it is throwing the error same as the previous. Yeah, I agree on the lower-cased thing. But this is from a separate REST API call which is not developed by me. So I have to take it as it is to align with the REST API data. `3.14` is definitely gonna work but I need to store a long int not a floating number. `(ex: 1486202620914)`

Comment: Lately I have found out that real-js is not currently supporting such type of number. So I decided to use `string` instead of using `decimal128` which is not a recommended way since there's no other solution for this.

Comment: Wait..  *decimal128* is a high-precision decimal. If you want to store a long, even a lesser precision decimal, then just use *double*

Comment: @Jay Yeah. It works Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decimal128 is a high-precision decimal number and it doesn't appear like that's what you are storing

> TemplateId: 1486202620914,

First, take a look a the [Field Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/data-types/field-types/) documentation for reference to options. Noting that `decimal128` is for high precision numbers e.g. lots of decimal places, and is a good solution for money

The BSON.Decimal128 type represents a 128-bit (16-byte) floating point number. This type is intended for use cases where decimal values must round exactly, e.g. financial data

[BSON.Decimal128 Quick Start](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/bson-data-types-decimal128/)

In your case, you could use a double as internally it's stored as a 64 bit number (decimal if needed), which is adequate for this use case. Initially I suggested a double but an int would likely be the best solution for code clarity if decimal is not needed. They both map to a Javascript number.

Comment: Can't use int for this much long number. It won't work in the queries like `.filtered(id=10303030033944049404)`

Comment: @HashanShalitha Ah, for sure. I was going by the example in the question `TemplateId: 1486202620914`. Glad it's working!